# Selecting min value of a group with id

Tags: select, group-by, min

Consider the following code:

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE
  (
    id INT IDENTITY ,
    DATA VARCHAR(100) ,
    code CHAR(1)
  )

INSERT  INTO @table
        ( data, code )
VALUES  ( 'xasdf', 'a' ),
        ( 'aasdf', 'a' ),
        ( 'basdf', 'a' ),
        ( 'casdf', 'b' ),
        ( 'Casdf', 'c' ),
        ( NULL, NULL )
```

I need to get a row with minimum data grouped by the code. Can I do this without nested queries?

Basically, what I want is something like this:

```
SELECT TOP ( 1 )
        id ,
        MIN(data)
FROM    @table
GROUP BY code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO. This is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * (SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY code DESC,data DESC) AS Row,
id,DATA,code
FROM @table) T where T.Row = 1